# Nessus Denial of Service checks

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners, nessus

What's the difference between the "Denial of Service" plugin family and other plugins with "DoS" in the Plugin Name but located in different families? Can those other plugins also cause DoSs during scans?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the nessus documentation. members of the "Denial of Service" family are direct checks that in some cases attempt to exploit the DoS vulnerability they are testing for.

> The Denial of Service family contains some plugins that could cause outages on a network if the Safe Checks option is not enabled, in addition to some useful checks that will not cause any harm. The Denial of Service family can be used in conjunction with Safe Checks to ensure that any potentially dangerous plugins are not run. However, it is recommended that the Denial of Service family not be used on a production network unless scheduled during a maintenance window and with staff ready to respond to any issues.

- https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/Content/Plugins.htm

Nessus plugins with DoS in the name and not in the 'Denial of Service' plugin family are often simple checks that verify if the target is vulnerable to X DoS vulnerability based on the reported version.